# How to delete a record in table from Azure Data Factory pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am having a scenario to delete a record from a table when there is an error in the pipeline. I am trying to run a query in Lookup Activity but it showing 'no data return'. I don't want to use the Mapping Data Flow for this.

How I can Achieve this?

Comment: How about using a Stored Procedure activity for this?

Comment: Yes we can do but is it possible to do it with ADF activities?

Answer (score 6):

In your lookup activity, I expect you have something like:

`delete from mytable where id = myid;`

So to make this work in lookup you need to have a result: simply change to:

```
delete from mytable where id = myid;
select 1 as success;
```